# Is there a way to set a php file as your index file on amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, drupal, hosting

Every time I try to make my amazon site use a .php index file it tells me that it is invalid.  Is S3 limited to use only index.html?
Is there a work around?

(Goal:  Setup S3 to host a community website to bring down the cost of hosting and have better backup services for our community)

Community site is running off of drupal.  I want to transfer all files from the current host and host them from amazon S3.  If any of you have a great tutorial of how this can be done I would kiss the ground!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

s3 won't run php code.  If you want to host your site on S3 then you basically have to generate a static copy of the site and upload that to S3.   If you want a dynamic site, like drupal, then you have to use some other hosting provider, or get your own server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information.  Any way I could use Amazon Cloud Services to run the community site?  Do you know of any tutorial I could follow?

Comment: You certainly can us EC2 for drupal . This tutorial looks good.  http://10jumps.com/blog/setup-your-own-drupal-amazon-ec2

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 or AWS Elastic Beanstalk are good choices for running complete websites (assuming you're looking to use the AWS platform).